# Split variables in SASS / SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I have a SASS variable like the following:

```
$surrounding-margin: 0 40px;
```

And I'm using it like this (the irrelevant properties have been removed):

```
#content {
  margin: $surrounding-margin;

  & #close {
    margin-right: -$surrounding-margin[1]; // If this was JS.
  }
}
```

Obviously, `-$surrounding-margin[1]` won't work. What will? I need the second value of the variable, in the negative. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use for example `nth` because it's just a list:

```
$surrounding-margin: 0 40px;

#content {
  margin: $surrounding-margin;

  & #close {
    margin-right: -(nth($surrounding-margin, 2));
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you change besides the selector name? I don't see any other difference.

Comment: You didn't use a id selector ( you used `c1` it has to be `#c1`)